# First split then join a subset of a string

Tags: c#, string, join, split

I have an input string as follows:

```
thumb_634735515600845357tchayat_november_200612.jpg
```

What I want to do is first *split* this string by `_`. And then take the resulting tokens at positions 1 to n and *join* them.

Specifically, with respect to my sample input, here is my desired output. As you can see, `thumb_` has been removed from the front of the string:

```
634735515600845357tchayat_november_200612.jpg
```

I know how to do the split. But then how do I do the join step that follows? I do realize that I can use a `for` loop to do the join. But is there a better way? I can't use a sub-string approach to do the join step because I have data before `thumb_`.

Finally, note that the `_` character that follows `thumb` is always the first instance of `_`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the `_` after the thumb is always the first instance then `Substring` should be perfectly viable in conjunction with `IndexOf`.

```
string newString = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("_") + 1);
```

This should take the substring starting at the character immediately following the first instance of the `_` character.

If you wish to get the *second* index of `_`, here's what I recommend:

```
int first = myString.IndexOf("_");
int second = mystring.Substring(first).IndexOf("_");
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/186667/1497596) by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) to the question ["Index of the nth occurrence of a string?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/186653/1497596) for support for this approach.

Comment: Since C#8 and the introduction of Range Structs, the recommended format for the first line of code would now be myString[(myString.IndexOf("_") + 1)..]

Answer (score 7):

If you don't like indexOf, but want Join instead:

```
String.Join("_",
   "thumb_634735515600845357tchayat_november_200612.jpg"
   .Split('_')
   .Skip(1)
   .ToArray())
```

Comment: +1: I like this if IndexOf is not available for some reason. It's a little "chattier" than the IndexOf solution, but a very good alternate.

Comment: It will not add _ in result as 634735515600845357tchayatnovember200612.jpg

Comment: actually you are right. that s the result for this and not reallyw hat i want

Answer (score 2):

After splitting and rearranging you can use Join method.

```
string new_value=String.Join("",your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Join`, but actually, it still use a loop inside.

```
String.Join("_", "thumb_634735515600845357tchayat_november_200612.jpg".Split('_').Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Comment: why do u have 1 and 3? what if u have more _?

Comment: @DarthVader Yes, you're right. Should use `Skip` instead. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @DarthVader Do you mean there are more `_` before "thumb"?

Answer (score 0):

UserRoles are the list of strings:

```
string.Join(",", userRoles.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

*Original post was on Aug. 31, 2015. The only thing that I've changed is the markup syntax because the original was wrong.*

The use of regular expressions can be very helpful.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string itemName = "thumb_634735515600845357tchayat_november_200612.jpg";
itemName = Regex.Match(itemName, @"(?<=(_)).*$").Value;
```

The "(?<=(_))" looks behind the first "_". Think of it as a starting point. The ".*$" gets everything from the starting point to the end of the line. "$" marks the end of the line.