# How do you split string to display as a list?

Tags: c#, split

So I am using textareas in a form to taking a list.

```
<tr>
   <td><label asp-for="Ingredients"></label></td>
   <td><textarea asp-for="Ingredients" ></textarea></td>
   <td><span asp-validation-for="Ingredients"></span></td>
</tr>
```

In my viewModel I have

```
[Required]
public string Ingredients { get; set; }
```

In the details it is called using

```
<div style="margin-left:15px"><u>Instructions:</u> <br /> 
@Model.Instructions</div>  <br />
```

It ends up displaying like:

```
item 1, item 2, item 3
```

I want it to display like:

```
item1
item2
item3
```

So how do I split the ingredients at the commas without displaying them while dropping them down a line each?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Split A String By Another String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/c-sharp-split-a-string-by-another-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split and join C# string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961868/split-and-join-c-sharp-string)

Comment: `Ingredients.Replace(", ", "<br />");` maybe?

Comment: Wouldn't that get escaped in the Razor view @RufusL ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Splitting Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559121/c-sharp-splitting-strings)

Comment: @rene Very possibly; it's out of my area. Hence the "maybe?" :)

Comment: easiest is probably a @foreach in your view over @Model.Instructions.Split(','); and then output the value and a `<br />`

Answer (score 1):

Note, it really doesn't matter if you're pulling from a database or not - a string is a string is a string.

Given that, on any string you can use [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_) to break it into an array based on some delimiter such as `','` in your case.
Then use [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.1) to make that array back into a string, joining with either markup (such as `"<br />"`) or `System.Environment.NewLine` for more of a plaintext representation.