# How to remove an element from a split String?

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm trying to remove an element/item/entry from a split string.

Let's say I got the `string` [*string_*] as follows:

```
string string_ = "one;two;three;four;five;six";
```

Then I split this **string** to get each, let's say, **item**:

```
string[] item = (string_.Split(";"));
```

I have no informations other than from **variables**. Depending on the user choice, I can get an item **value** and **index**.

Let's say that for this example, the user chose "***four***" which is the index "***3***".

How can I make my string look like the index 3 have been deleted, as `string_` would be equal to the following:

> "one;two;three;five;six"

I've tried multiple things and it seems like the only solution is to go through a **char** method.

Is that true or did I miss something?

---

EDIT to suggested already_posted_answer : 
Not quite the same question as my ITEM could be placed anywhere in my splitted string depending on the user selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First split then join a subset of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025690/first-split-then-join-a-subset-of-a-string)

Comment: Ten minutes, four wrong answers.  Read the answers carefully!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you need to write better variable names, `string_` is a horrible name.  Even something like "input" is way better.

```
string input = "one;two;three;four;five;six";
```

Next, you are on the right track by using [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx).  This will return an array of `string`:

```
string[] splitInput = input.Split(";");
```

The resulting string array will look like this:

```
//string[0] = one
//string[1] = two
//string[2] = three
//string[3] = four
//string[4] = five
//string[5] = six
```

## Removing with known index

If you want to remove a specific element from the array, you could make the result of Split() a `List<T>` by using [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and utilize the [`RemoveAt()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the resulting `List<T>`:

```
List<string> splitList = input.Split(';').ToList();
splitList.RemoveAt(3);

//Re-create the string
string outputString = string.Join(";", splitList);
//output is: "one;two;three;five;six"
```

## Remove all strings that match an input

If you need to remove items from the list without knowing their index but knowing the actual string, you can use LINQ's [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) to filter out the matching items:

```
//Get the input from the user somehow
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
IEnumerable<string> filteredList = input.Split(';')
                                      .Where(x => string.Compare(x, userInput, true) != 0);

//Re-create the string
string outputString = string.Join(";", filteredList);
```

I made a fiddle to demonstrate both methods [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bxnMr0)

Comment: You are awsome. Now i realise that i was doing my tests with string or int but i completly forgot about that neutral "var". Thank you so much. <3

Comment: Given "ToList()" call, this is not the best choice in terms of memory.

Comment: @YurySchkatula preemptive optimization is a bad idea.  The ToList is needed to use `RemoveAt()`

Comment: @maccettura, I understand your approach. Same time, at this case it is just poisoning the CPU cache and GC, and gives a bad habit for the topic starter.

Comment: @Yury If you are concerned about squeezing Performance Out of the cpu, you are in a totally wrong world. Try Rust or C

Comment: @Mightee, C# gives you a bigger hammer. So, misusing it would create much more performance penalty than misuse of Rust or C. Despite you have GC in C#, you MUST understand how it's working, to not seriously interfere with it. Really.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an array of string to list by following:

```
var list = new List<string>(item);
```

Once the list is created, you can easily remove an element:

```
var index = list.IndexOf("four");
list.RemoveAt(index);
```

Join the string back:

```
var result = String.Join(";", list.ToArray());
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: No need for `.IndexOf("four")`. `list.Remove("four")` does that for you.

Comment: @NamelessLambda Thanks for pointing out, `.Remove()` can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string array into a `List<string>`, and since you have the index of the item to be removed, you can remove the item using `RemoveAt`, then join the items back into one string.

Here's a complete console application example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string string_ = "one;two;three;four;five;six";
    string[] items = (string_.Split(';'));

    Console.WriteLine("Please select an item to remove:");
    for (int i = 0;i<items.Length;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}- {1}", (i + 1).ToString(), items[i]));
    }
    int num = 0;
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num);
    if (num > 0 && num <= items.Length)
    {
        List<string> itemsList = items.ToList();
        itemsList.RemoveAt(num - 1);
        string newString = string.Join(";", itemsList);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The new string is: {0}", newString));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid number!");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can employ LINQ. 
Initial plan is to split the string, then create a union of two enumerables: before and after the item. Something like this:

```
    // preconditions
    const int idx = 3;
    string string_ = "one;two;three;four;five;six";

    // actual transformation
    string[] item = (string_.Split(';'));
    var iterator = item.Take(idx).Concat(item.Skip(idx + 1));

    // output the results
    var result = string.Join(";", iterator);
    Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: This works like a charm as well. Thanks for your help. Care to explain how your solution is better for memory ? I'm new to memory optimisation and maccettura's solution is easier (at my level) for me to understand.

Comment: This solution is incorrect if there can be duplicates in the list. Why "union" and not "concat"?

Comment: Also, you are iterating the sequence twice, unnecessarily. You would do far better to write your own helper function: `public static IEnumerable<T> SkipOver<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int index) => items.Where((dummy, i) => i != index)` and then just say `string.Join(";", items.SkipOver(index))`  Now you are (1) iterating the sequence only once, and (2) you've built a helper method that might be more generally useful, that is self-describing.

Comment: @EricLippert, oh! You're quite right, I forgot about distinct nature of Union(). Going to amend my answer.

Comment: @Bo.Ga., that solution creates too much temp instances that could be used for nothing. Just imagine you visited a grocery shop, then returned home with full car of food, then dumped out to waste bin everything but small cake.

Comment: @YurySchkatula The return type of `string.Split()` is already an array.  Calling `.ToList()` from that is about as cheap of a conversion as you can get.  The resulting overhead in memory is just a few bytes (~40 to be more specific).  See the analysis [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lk5EHT)

Comment: @Bo.Ga. This solution would not have any noticeable improvement over mine.  See my comments, my basic [analysis](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lk5EHT) and read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15517544/2457029).

Answer (score -2):

Would this work for you?

If you create a new string like this, then replace the value of string_ with the value of the new string.

```
string string_ = "one;two;three;four;five;six";
string newstring = string_.Replace("four", "");
string_ = newstring.Replace(";;", ";");
```

Comment: What if we have several "four" occurrences and plan to remove just one of them? (not first one, not last one etc.)

Comment: I think the OP is offering a choice to the user. I haven't seen many menus with the same choice multiple times.

Comment: See one of next answers, and a comment by Eric Lippert about "twenty-four". It is absolutely correct question.