# find value after nth occurence of - using RegEx

Tags: regex

This expression

```
[A-Z]+(?=-\d+$)
```

find SS and BCP from following string

```
ANG-B31-OPS-PMR-MACE-SS-0229

ANG-RGN-SOR-BCP-0004
```

What I want to do is find the value after third "-" which is
 PMR in first string and BCP in second string

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The lookbehind and lookahead will exclude the pre and post part from the match

```
string mus = "ANG-B31-OPS-PMR-MACE-SS-0229";

string pat = @"(?<=([^-]*-){3}).+?(?=-)";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(mus, pat, RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: need to use the Regex only, cannot use C#

Comment: @user2188559 so what's the problem, take the pattern and use it. Also remove c# tag from the question

Answer (score 0):

What about simple `String.Split`?

```
string input = "ANG-B31-OPS-PMR-MACE-SS-0229";
string value = input.Split('-')[3]; // PMR
```

Comment: need to use the Regex only, cannot use C#

Comment: @user2188559 Do you want us to inline assembly or what?

Comment: This get me the correct value, but how can i say that within RegEx  so string value = input.Regex(); somethig like that

Comment: @user2188559 what the reason? String.Split is much faster and simpler. If you have fixed format of input (i.e. values separated by '-' with at least four values, and you need fourth of them) then RegeEx is overkill

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option it would be simpler to locate the third "-" and take a substring of the input. See [nth-index-of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/187394/39013).

```
var input = "ANG-B31-OPS-PMR-MACE-SS-0229";
input = input.Substring(input.NthIndexOf("-", 3) + 1, 3);
```

Comment: need to use the Regex only, cannot use C#