# regex to find value at a particular location

Tags: regex

Presently the regex is:

```
[A-Z]+(?=-\d+$)
```

This pulls out the correct value for most of the strings which follow the below format:

```
ANG-RGN-SOR-BCP-0004             i.e. BCP
```

However it pulls out `SS` for the following document instead of `PMR`:

```
ANG-B31-OPS-PMR-MACE-SS-0229
```

So basically I want to pull out the fourth term (between the hyphens), so it should pick `BCP` and `PMR`.

Comment: So you want to pull out the 4th item? What is the language?

Comment: If you can use "normal" language tools, split the string at `-` and access the fourth list element.

Comment: I want to use Regular Expression

Comment: possible duplicate of [find value after nth occurence of - using RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511502/find-value-after-nth-occurence-of-using-regex)

Answer (score 2):

The following regex will get the 4th item in group 1:

```
(?:[A-Z0-9]+-){3}([A-Z0-9]+)
```

- The first bit in `(?:...)` is a "non-capturing group" which acts like a group but won't appear in the backreference list.
- The next bit means "3 of these non-capturing groups".
- And finally, a capturing group to collect what you want.

I have assumed here that all the groups contain only uppercase letters and digits, you should modify the parts in `[square brackets]` to represent what these groups could be.

---

A more easily understandable method in Python:

```
a = "ANG-B31-OPS-PMR-MACE-SS-0229"
part = a.split('-')[3]

print part
```

This gives "PMR".

Comment: This is getting the first four values i.e. ANG-B31-OPS-PMR , I just want to read the value between 3rd and fourth dash i.e. JUst PMR and BCP

Comment: You need to look in group 1. Group 0 will be the whole match, which as you say is the first 4 items with dashes.

Answer (score 1):

This should suit your needs ([demo](http://regexr.com?346rs)):

```
(?:.+?-){3}([^-]+)
```

You'll be able to access the *fourth term* in the first capturing group.

Comment: This is getting the first four values i.e. ANG-B31-OPS-PMR , I just want to read the value between 3rd and fourth dash i.e. JUst PMR and BCP

Comment: @user2188559 Yes, the value you're looking for get found in the *first capturing group* of the regex. What language are you using? I could show you how to access this *group*.