# Regex select all after nth occurance of character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in the following format and I'm trying to return all the data after the 3rd occurrence of the ':' character as in the example below.

```
user_name_1, 10:46:36 activity_name_1 : the text to be returned
```

So far I have the regex `\:.*` that returns everything after the first occurrence, eg. `:46:36 activity_name_1 : the text to be returned`

If I modify it to `\:{3}.*` eg. to look for the 3rd instance, the regex will not return any matches. It looks like it should be a very simple query but nothing I've tried seems to work.

I've already found the following question [find value after nth occurence of - using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511502/find-value-after-nth-occurence-of-using-regex) however in this case they're returning only the next 3 digits after the nth character and not the entire remaining string.

Comment: If you don't care about Safari, this will work: `/(?<=(.*:){3}).*/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:[^:]*:){3}\s*(\S.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Fxocf/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^:]*:){3}` - three occurrences of any zero or more chars other than a `:` and then a `:` char
- `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\S.*)` - Group 1: a non-whitespace char and then the rest of the line.

See the JavaScript  demo:

```js
const text = "user_name_1, 10:46:36 activity_name_1 : the text to be returned";
const match = text.match(/^(?:[^:]*:){3}\s*(\S.*)/)
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1])
}
```

Comment: Just tested this and it's working perfectly for my use case, really appreciate the explanation for each selector as well!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest not using regex for this. `split()` the string by the `:` character and remove the first two elements of the resulting array.

You can turn the result back in to a string if necessary by using `join()`:

```js
let input = 'user_name_1, 10:46:36 activity_name_1 : the text to be returned : foo : bar';

let arr = input.split(':');
arr.splice(0, 3);
console.log(arr);

let output = arr.join(':').trim();
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is what I tried initally, however there are some scenarios where the text to be returned could also contain one or more : symbols which makes splitting and joining very messy

Comment: In that case `join()` the array back together using `:` - I edited the question to show this use case