# How do I replace a specific occurrence of a string in a string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string which may contain "title1" twice in it.

e.g.

> server/api/shows?title1=its always sunny in philadelphia&title1=breaking bad ...

I need to change the second instance of the word "title1" to "title2"

I already know how to identify whether there ARE two instances of the string in the string.

```
int occCount = Regex.Matches(callingURL, "title1=").Count;

if (occCount > 1)
{
     //here's where I need to replace the second "title1" to "title2"
}
```

I know we can probably use Regex here but I'm not able to get the replace on the second instance. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: if there are 3 instances of the word `title1` do you need to change the third one to `title3`?

Comment: This sounds like a broader problem to me.

Comment: it will NEVER have more than 2 instances

Comment: you know the old saying `NEVER SAY NEVER`

Comment: I have checks to ensure the string will never have more than 2 instances. the outer string gets built on user selections on the screen and i account for the correct selections...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will only replace the second instance of `title1` (and any subsequent instances) after the first:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=title1.*)title1", "title2");
```

However, if there are more than 2 instances, it may not be what you want. It's a little crude, but you can do this to handle any number of occurrences:

```
int i = 1;
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"title1", m => "title" + i++);
```

Comment: pswg, I know I already accepted your answer but I just tried to do exactly the same thing but with the word "episodetitle1" and it's not giving me the same results. Care to give another hand? callingURL = Regex.Replace(callingURL, @"(?<=episodetitle1.*)episodetitle1", "episodetitle2");

Comment: @Rj. What's the input string?

Comment: something like this: server/api/Shows?title1=breaking%20bad&title2=two%20and%20a%20half%20men&episodetitle1=pilot&episodetitle2=a%20big%20bag%20of%20dog

Comment: @Rj. Well it looks like that string has already had the second `episodetitle1` replaced with `episodetitle2`, but in any case, the pattern works for me whether you use `title1` or `episodetitle1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex replace `MatchEvaluator` and give it a "state":

```
string callingURL = @"server/api/shows?title1=its always sunny in philadelphia&title1=breaking bad";

int found = -1;
string callingUrl2 = Regex.Replace(callingURL, "title1=", x =>
{
    found++;
    return found == 1 ? "title2=" : x.Value;
});
```

The replace can be one-lined by using the postfixed `++` operator (quite unreadable).

```
string callingUrl2 = Regex.Replace(callingURL, "title1=", x => found++ == 1 ? "title2=" : x.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can specify a count, and an index to start searching at

```
string str = @"server/api/shows?title1=its always sunny in philadelphia&title1=breaking bad ...";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"title1");
str = regex.Replace(str, "title2", 1, str.IndexOf("title1") + 6);
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but why would you use a regular expression in the last step? You could simply do a `string.Replace`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g does `string.Replace` have a field specifying where you start the search?

Comment: Nope, you're right. You'd have to do a couple of `string.Substring`'s first (like a one answer had, which is now deleted).

Comment: Just what I needed - couldn't find this in static API. I'm disappointed that the static method of same name is missing this basic feature; it tricked me into believing that the API lacked it. IMHO great example of how you shouldn't overload method names if you're going to re-implement the static / non-static method with different feature sets.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps make use of a negative lookahead:

```
title1(?!.*title1)
```

And replace with `title2`.

See how it's working [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/vP0vU9).

Comment: @Anirudh The user already made sure with the `if` that there are two instances of `title1`.

Comment: it can have a single occurance

Answer (score 0):

I found this link immediately on a google search.

[C# - indexOf the nth occurrence of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186653/c-sharp-indexof-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string)

Get the IndexOf the first occurrence of the string.

Use the returned IndexOf's startIndex +1 for the starting position of the second IndexOf.

Substring it into two strings at the appropriate index of the "1" character.

Concat it back together with the "2" character.

Answer (score 0):

The way P.S.W.G did is really awesome. but below I mentioned one simple way to get it done for those who do have problem in lambda and regex expression..;)

int index = input.LastIndexOf("title1=");

string output4 = input.Substring(0, index - 1) + "&title2" + input.Substring(index + "title1".Length, input.Length - index - "title1".Length);