# Get index of next same character

Tags: c#, string, substring, streamreader

I have a file like this:
"Something, something, something, something, something"

And I want to get the index of third "," with:

```
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("File.txt");
string s=sr.Readline();    
string c=s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(',')));
```

Comment: Assuming C# ; [C# - indexOf the nth occurrence of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186653/c-sharp-indexof-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for previous answer, I created a function for you, try this, You need to pass your string, character to find and occurance number as parameters. [Here](https://ideone.com/S7eKIz) is a demo.

```
public static int getSpecifiedIndexOf(string str,char ch,int index)
{
    int i = 0,o=1;
    while ((i = str.IndexOf(ch, i)) != -1)
    {
        if(o==index)return i;
        o++;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify which character do you want and which occurance in next parameter

```
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("File.txt");
string s=sr.Readline();    
string c=s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(',',3)));
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/S7eKIz) is your solution

Comment: you didn't understand me. I have "Something1, something2, something3, something4. And I want "something3".

Comment: your starting point for substring is 0 so it will trim string from 0th position

Comment: That `int` parameter to `IndexOf` [is the index to start at, not the occurrence number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx).

Comment: Hmm, don't like this "I want" attitude. We're here to help, but when expectations are that we're in any way obligated to write code for you, that does make me feel a little uncomfortable.