# get char position in textBox

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the index of a each char in the text "ABCDCEF" (textBox.text). The problem is that the first 'C' index is 2 and the second C index is 4 but the second 'C' index in the result is 2 too.

This is the code:

```
        foreach (char character in textBox1.Text)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(character + " - " + textBox1.Text.IndexOf(character));
        }
```

Result:

char - index

A - 0

B - 1

**C - 2**

D - 3

**C - 2**

E - 5

F - 6

The correct result should be:

char - index

A - 0

B - 1

**C - 2**

D - 3

**C - 4**

E - 5

F - 6

Why it's happening?

Thanks

Comment: Its because you need to increase your startIndex in each iteration!

Comment: As Jesus said. Have a look at [Get index of next same character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633861/get-index-of-next-same-character)

Comment: @Tone the way said it I thought you meant Christ! I hadn't seen the comment above though...

Answer (score 2):

[`string.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) returns *first* occurrence of a character, that's why it returns index `2` for `c` lookup.

MSDN Says,

> Reports the zero-based **index of the first occurrence of a specified
>   Unicode character or string within this instance.** The method returns
>   -1 if the character or string is not found in this instance.

You could convert it to `for` loop and get index for each character.

```
for(int i=0;i<textBox1.Text.Length;i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text[i] + " - " + i); 
}
```

Comment: I tried to insert a separator with for loop but did not work. This is the code:

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

            {

                if (char.IsUpper(textBox1.Text[i]))

                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(i, " | ");

            }