# Visual Basic removing remaing string after delimiter

Tags: vb.net, string, delimiter

I'm trying to remove the last part of the string to make it more presentable. The string looks like this

```
Stringname.number.RemainingStringTobeRemoved
```

Is there a way to remove the last part without using `string.Substring(0,string.Length-10)`?
I want it to be dynamic, the string I'll be removing is not a constant number.

My initial idea was to use **delimiter** to identify the starting point of the part I want to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My initial idea was using delimiter to identify the starting point of the part I want to remove.

That's a good idea if your string is always the same format and the substring you want to remove does not contain that delimiter. Take a look at [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

**Spoiler:**

> Dim s = "Stringname.number.RemainingStringTobeRemoved"
>     Dim r = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf("."))

Comment: What if I want to remove everything after the 2nd "."?

Comment: @user2918970 you could use a function that finds the nth occurrence of a string inside another one like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/187394/142637) and use that together with `Substring`

Answer (score 0):

Using a delimiter is one way. You can use the `Split` method to split the string into parts at the `.`.

```
Dim FullString As String = "Stringname.number.RemainingStringTobeRemoved"
Dim StringParts() As String = Strings.Split(FullString, ".", 3)
Return StringParts(0) & StringParts(1)
```

The Split method returns an array of String that contains the parts. The array will contain the following items

- Stringname
- number
- RemainingStringTobeRemoved

The delimiters are omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Split to achieve this

```
String s = "Stringname.number.RemainingStringTobeRemoved"
Dim words As String() = s.Split(New Char() {"."c})
String RequiredString = words(0) & words(1)
```

The RequiredString is what you need