# How to remove all but the first occurences of a character from a string?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string of text and want to ensure that it contains at most one single occurrence of a specific character (`,`). Therefore I want to keep the first one, but simply remove all further occurrences of that character.

How could I do this the most elegant way using C#?

Answer (score 4):

This works, but not the most elegant for sure :-)

```
string a = "12,34,56,789";
int pos = 1 + a.IndexOf(',');
return a.Substring(0, pos) + a.Substring(pos).Replace(",", string.Empty);
```

Comment: I find it elegant ;) Has just one drawback if you want to keep 2 chars f.e.

Comment: @TimSchmelter What do you mean by "keep 2 chars"?

Comment: @silkfire: well, try to specify that you don't want to remove all but the first, instead all but the first 2

Comment: I see what you mean now. For that you could replace `a.IndexOf` with a method that returns the Nth occurrence of a substring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186653/get-the-index-of-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string

Answer (score 2):

You could use a counter variable and a [`StringBuilder`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=StringBuilder&hl=en&gl=UK&gws_rd=ssl) to create the new string efficiently:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
int maxCount = 1;
int currentCount = 0;
char specialChar = ',';
foreach(char c in text)
    if(c != specialChar || ++currentCount <= maxCount)
        sb.Append(c);
text = sb.ToString();
```

This approach is not the shortest but it's efficient and you can specify the char-count to keep.

Here's a more "elegant" way using LINQ:

```
int commasFound = 0; int maxCommas = 1;
text = new string(text.Where(c => c != ',' || ++commasFound <= maxCommas).ToArray());
```

I don't like it because it requires to modify a variable from a query, so it's causing a side-effect.

Comment: I'd call the LINQ one pretty elegant :)

Comment: @Rawling: edited my answer to comment why i don't like it (even if i love LINQ).

Comment: I really like your LINQ statement, but I don't understand the side effects you mention yet. What are you expecting to happen there?

Comment: In this case it works without a problem. But the use and initialisation of local variables in linq queries is a bomb which can explode under more complex situations or queries. This variable has only one state but a query can be executed in multiple ways, for example if you include OrderBy. So best practices is to use a method for such tasks where the variable is encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function like the following one that would split the string into two sections based on the location of what you were searching (via the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method) for and it would only remove matches from the second section (using [`String.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)) :

```
public static string RemoveAllButFirst(string s, string stuffToRemove)
{
    // Check if the stuff to replace exists and if not, return the original string
    var locationOfStuff = s.IndexOf(stuffToRemove);
    if (locationOfStuff < 0)
    {
        return s;
    }
    // Calculate where to pull the first string from and then replace the rest of the string
    var splitLocation = locationOfStuff + stuffToRemove.Length;
    return s.Substring(0, splitLocation) +  (s.Substring(splitLocation)).Replace(stuffToRemove,"");
}
```

You could simply call it by using :

```
var output = RemoveAllButFirst(input,",");
```

A prettier approach might actually involve building an extension method that handled this a bit more cleanly :

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
     public static string RemoveAllButFirst(this string s, string stuffToRemove)
     {
           // Check if the stuff to replace exists and if not, return the 
           // original string
           var locationOfStuff = s.IndexOf(stuffToRemove);
           if (locationOfStuff < 0)
           {
               return s;
           }
           // Calculate where to pull the first string from and then replace the rest of the string
           var splitLocation = locationOfStuff + stuffToRemove.Length;
           return s.Substring(0, splitLocation) +  (s.Substring(splitLocation)).Replace(stuffToRemove,"");
     }
}
```

which would be called via :

```
var output = input.RemoveAllButFirst(",");
```

You can [see a working example of it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fxXViO).

Comment: `StringExtensions` needs to be static class and first param needs to be `this string s`

Comment: For some reason it looks like my response had been submitted mid-response without me noticing. I've updated the function accordingly. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are elegant, right?

```
Regex.Replace("Eats, shoots, and leaves.", @"(?<=,.*),", "");
```

This replaces every comma, as long as there is a comma before it, with nothing.

(Actually, it's probably not elegant - it may only be one line of code, but it may also be `O(n^2)`...)

Comment: when I put this in a tester it doesn't work. A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width

Comment: @user1040975 You might be using a different flavour of regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't deal with large strings and you reaaaaaaly like Linq oneliners:

```
public static string KeepFirstOccurence (this string @string, char @char)
{
    var index = @string.IndexOf(@char);
    return String.Concat(String.Concat(@string.TakeWhile(x => @string.IndexOf(x) < index + 1)), String.Concat(@string.SkipWhile(x=>@string.IndexOf(x) < index)).Replace(@char.ToString(), ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static string KeepFirstOccurance(this string str, char c)
    {
        int charposition = str.IndexOf(c);
        return str.Substring(0, charposition + 1) +
                   str.Substring(charposition, str.Length - charposition)
                   .Replace(c, ' ').Trim();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty short with Linq; split string into chars, keep distinct set and join back to a string.

```
text = string.Join("", text.Select(c => c).Distinct());
```