# get string after second space

Tags: c#, string, substring

If I have a string like this

```
@"400 ERROR The second argument must be larger than the first."
```

How do I extract the part that says `"The second argument must be larger than the first."`?

Comment: If all your inputs are of same format then why don't you make a try with `.Substring()` by taking index of `ERROR`

Comment: @un-lucky could be `@"1024 WARNING Something something something..."`

Comment: Get the index of the [2nd space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186653/c-sharp-indexof-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string), then get the substring after that. Or someone can come along with regex probably.

Comment: When in doubt, blame [RegEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you'll have two problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string error = @"400 ERROR The second argument must be larger than the first.";
var ind1 = error.IndexOf(' ');
var ind2 = error.IndexOf(' ', ind1 + 1);
var substring = error.Substring(ind2);
```

How ever this may potentially fail in various cases. for example having multiple spaces behind each other. using this method may be error-prone.

Regex is better option.

```
string error = @"400 ERROR The second argument must be larger than the first.";
Regex regex = new Regex("^\\d+ *(ERROR|WARNING) *(?<Message>.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
var message = regex.Match(error).Groups["Message"].ToString();
```

You can add as many as patterns you want in your first capture.like this `(ERROR|WARNING|HINT|etc)`

Comment: How do I convert message to a string?

Comment: by calling `ToString()` will edit. btw `Match` method will return a `Match` . `Message` is a name I chose for the second group to be able to capture second group by name (so its more readable).

Comment: @minseong also you can have this Regex as `static` field. if this method is used frequently it is recommended to make `new Regex(...)` once and use it as much as you want.

Comment: I ended up using the second solution, having the regex match groups was very useful in other parts of my program as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var source = @"400 ERROR The second argument must be larger than the first.";
var result = String.Join(" ", source.Split(' ').Skip(2));
```

That gives me the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = String.Join(" ",error.split(' ').Skip(2))
```

Or this

```
var output = Regex.Replace(ErrorText,@"\d+?\s\w+","");
```